# PHP preg_split adds a blank array key that can't be cleared by array_filter because there's a 'space' in it

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to use `preg_split` to split a text that has an odd number of new lines between paragraphs but there are also on some of those new lines(also odd) a few 'spaces'(empty spaces) but the regular expression that I'm using is not able to bypass those 'spaces' and instead it includes them in my array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Dummy text
    [2] =>  
    [3] => more dummy text after some lines
    [5] =>  
    [7] => even more dummy text
)
```

Here is the regular expression example: https://3v4l.org/2aMNN

```
preg_split('/(\r\n|\n|\r)/', $p)
```

So far I've used a `foreach` loop to clean that up:

```
foreach($arr as $v){
    if(!empty($v){
         //do something
    }
}
```

But I'm pretty sure there's a better solution to this X_X :-s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) with the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag to remove completely empty values from the output, but you also need to include whitespace adjacent to newlines in your regex to avoid getting lines which just have spaces in them in your output. This will work (`$p` is copied from your demo):

```
$arr  = preg_split('/[\r\n]+\s*/', $p, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($arr);
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [0] => Dummy text
    [1] => more dummy text after some lines
    [2] => even more dummy text 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/VhYWV)

Comment: Hey @Nick, thank you sooooo much for taking time to answer! <3:D It works perfectly <3

Answer (score 1):

Use the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag.

```
$p ='
foo

bar


biz

';
    
print_r(preg_split('/(\r\n|\n|\r)/', $p, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => bar
    [2] => biz
)
```

[See it live](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ce6a78b4db64d55d3c431a7e0b502a75bf744bce)

For reference

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

> **PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY**
>
> If this flag is set, only non-empty pieces will be returned by preg_split().

**As a Bonus**

A regex such as this `'/[\r\n]/'` is sufficient for what you want.  Because `\r` is in it, `\r\n` is also in it, and `\n` is in there too(big surprise right).  You might be thinking "well on windows it's \r\n, won't that split 2x". Sure it will, but it doesn't matter because of the No Empty flag.

Even if that worries you you can just add a `+` to the end like `'/[\r\n]+/'`, so :-p, which now that I think of it, might be a bit more "faster" but I digress.

P.S. If you use the last one with the `+`, you don't even need the flag (if you trim it). So there 2 answers  [Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3e96458f478ec0550e315c9df34f24a47c35514e).

Simple!

Comment: Hey @ArtisticPhoenix, thank you for taking time to help me event tho i've used a previous answer cause it was closerX_X thank youuuuuuuuuu! X_X